# Newbie question about Dependency Injection when a method needs to create new objects

Tags: language-agnostic, dependency-injection

I've been reading about dependency injection and have a simple question.  I can understand how via constructor or setter injection required dependencies are autowired by the DI framework.  What happens when an object decides it needs to create a new object due to some business process?  Do I need to always create a Factory in these situations?  To make it a less abstract question, here is an example.

Let's say I'm writing a game of Asteriods.  There's a ship in the middle which can spin around and shoot the asteriods.  Assume that the ship has been created and approriate things injected.  When `playerShip.shoot()` is called we need to create a `bullet` object.  The bullet object needs to know which way it is going (`direction`) and where to start (`point`).

Normally, I would do something like this:

```
bullet = new Bullet( direction, point );
```

However, that tightly couples the PlayerShip class to the Bullet class.  How should this work under dependency injection?  Do I need to create a BulletFactory interface and inject an implementation of that into the ship?

Edit: I'm not actually writing asteriods.  This was a simple example that I thought people would understand.  I wanted something that needed to be created a runtime (not while "wiring up objects") that also had parameters to it's constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends if you just going to have just one bullet type...

If just one then I would say you'd be ok.

But if you have a **Bullet, DoubleBullet, PowerBullet, NukeBullet, etc.**

Then I would make Bullet base class and all the other Derrived from it

Then I would make Bullet factory and it would have CreateBullet, CreatePowerBullet, etc.

The other question is will anything else be making a bullet? If so then I would create a factory to consolidate the creation logic in one place...

Otherwise it smells like your using DI just to be using DI...

Comment: Also, if "bullet" itself was a very complex object with its own object tree you'll probably want a factory to avoid Ship having dependencies to Bullet's dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You've pretty much got it. If you want to be decoupled with the `Bullet` class, then in my opinion the best solution is to inject a factory that can create `Bullet` objects.

Note that you have several levels of indirection you can take, each giving you more flexibility, but requiring more code and possibly being more difficult to understand. The simplest is to have `BulletFactory` and `Bullet` both be concrete types. This means you can't easily have different implementations of them, but you can still extend them both and pass in a subclass of `BulletFactory` that returns subclasses of `Bullet`. If your only purpose for injection is to make unit tests easier, this is the route I would take. Of course, you can also make `BulletFactory` an interface, or `Bullet` an interface, or both. If you're going to have different implements of either for non-testing purposes, this is the route I would take.

Finally, you have to decide if the benefits of decoupling the `Bullet` class from your `PlayerShip` class are worth it. Tight coupling is not evil and shouldn't be avoided at all costs—it makes sense in some contexts, and not in others. Only experience will help you figure out when to couple classes and when to decouple them.

Answer (score 1):

The dependency injection is not suitable for this case. If you create a factory for this you will overuse design patterns. You can't decouple the entire system, in this case Ship has a composition with Bullet, and in case you need any more complex than that another pattern (not necessarily DI) might be adequate.

Comment: So, only use DI for service type objects and singletons?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this smells like over-architecting.  Nevertheless, off the top of my head, you could have a property that stores the bullet Type and then have your DI framework (ninject here) create the bullet.

```
public Type BulletType {get; set;}

public void fire()
{
    var b = (BulletType) kernel.get(BulletType);
    b.fire(point, direction);
}
```

Comment: So kernel.get(BulletType) will lookup the class name I've specified externally and create me an instance of that?  Does this mean that point and direction can not be passed in the constructor but have to be set subsequent to creation?

Comment: Yep, kernel does the lookup & creation in the Ninject Framework. And it doesn't take parameters like point.  Is that a problem?